# How to remove code repeatings in this situation

Tags: python, dry, discord.py

I'm looking for a solution to remove code repeatings.
I have a lot of duplicates of this line:

```py
await msg.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])
```

In my code

```py
async def untrack(ctx, playerName=None):
  author = ctx.message.author
  channel = ctx.message.channel
  await ctx.message.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])

  if playerName is None: 
    if config['bot']['track_only_one']:
      players = db.getAuthorTrackedPlayers(author, channel)
      if len(players) > 0:
        playerId = players[0]
        playerName = db.getPlayerNameById(playerId)
      else:
        msg = await ctx.send('{}, your track list already empty'.format(author.mention))
        await msg.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])
        return False
    else:
      msg = await ctx.send('{}, type !pdb-untrack \'player_name\''.format(author.mention))
      await msg.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])
      return False

  playerId = db.getPlayerIdByName(playerName)
  if playerId == -1:
    msg = await ctx.send('{}, {} doesn\'t found in tracked players'.format(author.mention, playerName))
    await msg.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])
    return False

  if db.removePlayerFromAuthor(author, channel, playerId):
    msg = await ctx.send('{}, {} removed from your track list'.format(author.mention, playerName))
    await msg.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])
  else:
    msg = await ctx.send('{}, {} is not in your track list'.format(author.mention, playerName))
    await msg.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])
```

Maybe somebody can help me to understand how to fix this problem.

**UPDATE**
New code after your suggestions

```
async def send_destruct_message(ctx, message=None):
  if message:
    msg = await ctx.send(message)
  else:
    msg = ctx.message
  await msg.delete(delay = config['delay']['delete'])

async def untrack(ctx, player_name=None):
  author = ctx.message.author
  channel = ctx.message.channel
  await ctx.message.delete(delay=config['delay']['delete'])

  if player_name is not None:
    player_id = db.get_player_id_by_name(player_name)
  else: 
    if not config['bot']['track_only_one']:
      await send_destruct_message(ctx, '{}, type !pdb-untrack \'player_name\''.format(author.mention))
      return False  
    try:
      player_id = db.get_author_tracked_players(author, channel)[0]
      player_name = db.get_player_name_by_id(player_id)  
    except IndexError:
      await send_destruct_message(ctx, '{}, your track list already empty'.format(author.mention))
      return False

  if player_id == -1:
    await send_destruct_message(ctx, '{}, {} doesn\'t found in tracked players'.format(author.mention, player_name))
    return False

  if not db.remove_player_from_author(author, channel, player_id):
    await send_destruct_message(ctx, '{}, {} is not in your track list'.format(author.mention, player_name))
    return False

  await send_destruct_message(ctx, '{}, {} removed from your track list'.format(author.mention, player_name))
  return True
```

Comment: In addition to the other answers, you could also clarify your code by also using functions to divide your code into something more functional. Such as : `if player_name is None: get_new_player_name()`. The lines that are into `get_new_player_name()` will only be processed by the user if he wants, and doesn't need to bother understanding what these lines do. Because the name of the function tells him. To me, it's always better to avoid if, if, else, if, elif, elif, else statements at a single place. That are necessary, but can confuse the reader if put at everyone's sight.

Comment: @IMCoins Thank you. Will try to remake it with your suggestions.

Comment: @IMCoins Sholud i make new def inside my untrack function if i use this part of code only once?

Comment: It depends. It's up to you and your team preferences I would say. If the function needs only be used by this function, in this particular file, I would prefix the function with an underscore. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), I quote : `_single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.`

Comment: @IMCoins Exactly what i want to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, and I strongly recommend to use `player_name` instead of `playerName`

```
async def delete_message(ctx, message=None):
    if message:
        msg = await ctx.send(message)
    else:
        msg = ctx.message
    await msg.delete(delay = config['delay']['delete'])

async def untrack(ctx, player_name=None):
  author, channel = ctx.message.author, ctx.message.channel
  await delete_message(ctx)

  if player_name is None: 
    if config['bot']['track_only_one']:
      players = db.getAuthorTrackedPlayers(author, channel)
      if len(players) > 0:
        player_id = players[0]
        player_name = db.getPlayerNameById(playerId)
      else:
        await delete_message(ctx, '{}, your track list already empty'.format(author.mention))
        return False
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! About code style. The whole project was coded with camelCase. So i continue to code in same style.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that does what those two lines do.

```
async def send_message (ctx, config, message):
    msg = await ctx.send(message)
    await msg.delete(delay = config['delay']['delete'])
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
if playerid == 1:
    await send_message(ctx, config, '{}, {} doesn\'t found in tracked players'.format(author.mention, playerName)
    return False

if db.removePlayerFromAuthor(author, channel, playerId):
    await send_message(ctx, config, '{}, {} removed from your track list'.format(author.mention, playerName))
else:
    await send_message(ctx, config, '{}, {} is not in your track list'.format(author.mention, playerName))
```